# -rewrite-objc and Objective-C in clang

Tags: clang, objective-c-runtime

Recently, I have one problem. The clang can translate Objective-C to c++ use -rewrite-objc.
So I think, the first step. clang compile Objective-C to C++. And then compile only can use c++ compiler. Is it do like this?
clang first translate Objective-C to C++ with runTime, and then compile to the machine code?

Answer (score 5):

`-rewrite-objc` exists to translate ObjC to C++ so it can be compiled in the Visual Studio.   It is still Objective-C semantics and you still need the objective-c runtime.   It is not magically converting Objective-C to the C++ OO architecture.

This is much more like when Objective-C was implemented as a pre-compiler extension.

It all relies on the fact that Objective-C classes are just C structures with fancy behavior and objective-c method calls all can be translated to calls to `objc_msgSend()`.

Comment: Thank you. But I also what to know, dose Clang translate OC to machine code directly instead of to C++ first when compiling?

Comment: It translates it to C++ code (mostly C, really) before compilation;  specifically, before the visual studio compiler takes over, typically.

Comment: sorry for disturb you. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234485/how-does-objective-c-compile), the top answer confuse me. So dose any C/C++ IR live when compiling OC?

Comment: @merito Totally different situation;  that question is talking about compiling code to IR.   This question is referring to the ObjC rewriter.  The goal of the rewriter is to spit straight C/C++ **code** that can be compiled by another compiler -- typically the Visual C++ compiler in Visual Studio.