# What's the relationship between Objective-C source code and after clang -rewrite-objc C++ code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, clang

When I write some Objective-C source code, I can use `clang -rewrite-objc FILENAME.m` to translate this code to C++ source code. What is the relationship between the C++ source code and the original Objective-C source code?

Objective-C is a superset of C (but not C++) so why can Objective-C be translated to C++, not C? When Objective-C code is compiled, linked and run on iOS or macOS, is it precompiled to C++, then linked and so on?

Comment: I found bbum's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561285/rewrite-objc-and-objective-c-in-clang. But I still confused about why he said `-rewrite-objc` makes Obj-C could be compiled by Visual Studio? If we use Xcode to build our Obj-C projects, is there a `-rewrite-objc` step exist?

Comment: Apple has programs for Windows. iTunes being the best known one. So I imagine he meant that those programs are developed in Visual Studio in Windows so they can be built for Windows. So, to reuse code from the macOS versions of these programs in Windows versions built in Visual Studio they have to translate the existing Obj-C code to C++ so VS can build it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C can be translated to straight C still.   There isn't anything in the ObjC runtime API that requires C++, though the innards are implemented in C++ here and there.   I don't think this has changed.  The rewriter, however, may be generating C++ simply because that is the most convenient/efficient target to generate.

There is no translation step in Xcode's build process.   It compiles *native* Objective-C code;  that is, the ObjC is converted straight to the interim format that the compiler uses to then generate executables, just like C++, C and any other language the compiler natively supports.

The translator exists explicitly because there is no Objective-C compiler in Visual Studio.  Prior to the rewriter, a different compiler was used to compile ObjC code into libraries on Windows and then combine those libraries with code compiled in Visual Studio to yield the final applications.

It worked, but debugging was really really complicated because any call stack that walked between the two code generation styles could not be debugged from a single debugger!