# Why can I redeclaration variable in one scope in C++?

Tags: c++, clang, objective-c-blocks

I write some test code in Objc, and use Clang -rewrite-objc to convert it to C++, and found there seems like an error of redeclaration in C++ code, but the code actually works fine.
**Test code:**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *var = @"";
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(9 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@",var);
            NSObject *var = @"";
            NSLog(@"%@",var);
        });
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**And use `clang -rewrite-objc main.m` rewrite to C++:**

```
static void __main_block_func_0(struct __main_block_impl_0 *__cself) {       
    NSString *var = __cself->var; // bound by copy 
NSLog((NSString*)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_n0_4hrn9qgn3blbbt6ybq79lzt00000gn_T_main_e76f89_mi_2,var);
    NSObject *var = (NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_n0_4hrn9qgn3blbbt6ybq79lzt00000gn_T_main_e76f89_mi_3;
    NSLog((NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_n0_4hrn9qgn3blbbt6ybq79lzt00000gn_T_main_e76f89_mi_4,var);
}
```

so why can I redefine `var` **in the scope of figure of the block** ?

I think this case is not suitable for  `local var` and `global var` in C++.

Thanks if any help or discuss~

Comment: Do you compile the "converted to C++" as C++, or do you compile the original ObjC? It looks like the converter has produced invalid C++

Comment: @Caleth See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739212/1271826. Given the OP's dozen line sample code, this command produces `main.cpp`, a 100,000 line file that includes the snippet the OP shared with us. It’s not, by any practical definition, valid C++, but if bbum is right, there must be some Visual Studio option that permits this non-standard syntax.